# How to return top 100 rows by a column value and then randomize theese top 100 rows?

Tags: sql-server, database

I'm using MS SQL and i've managed to create a query that selects top 100 rows and randomize them like this

```
SELECT TOP 100 * FROM Inlagg  ORDER BY NEWID()
```

I've also managed to create a query that returns the top 100 rows according to the column likes like this

```
SELECT TOP 100 * FROM Inlagg  ORDER BY Likes DESC
```

My question is now, how can i target theese top 100 rows by Likes and then randomize theese top 100 values?

Any help or input highly appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use something like

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT TOP 100 * FROM Inlagg  ORDER BY Likes DESC) as T
ORDER BY NEWID()
```

or (for those who prefers common table expressions not subqueries)

```
WITH CTE_TOP as (SELECT TOP 100 * FROM Inlagg  ORDER BY Likes DESC)
SELECT * FROM CTE_TOP ORDER BY NEWID();
```

Answer (score 1):

may be this also works

```
 select * 
    from Inlagg   t1
    inner join
    (
      select distinct top 100 Likes
      from Inlagg  
      order by Likes
    ) t2
      on t1.Inlaggid = t2.Inlaggid
```

**Guys i'm sorry to say that i'm unable to send comments may be java Api is not supporting my  browser.Why it wont works it will give top 100 records based on the order by combination.Coming to the performance issue may be this table column will have clustered or non clustered index will be there.Scan lookups will be reduced i just said it is another way not the exact solution**

Comment: In the case of this question (only 100 rows), you won't be able to tell. But that will develop catastrophic performance drops as you increase the number of rows queried. Check the other answers for the correct and most standard method to achieve this.

Comment: @JohnnyBell interesting comment after reading your wrong answer.

Comment: Even if it hasn't produced the expected result, using joins like this will create performance issues, regardless of my answer.